# Usage of "hold the screen"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I am developing a game. When you tap or hold the screen with your finger, character goes up.

I want to display a tutorial at the beginning of the game. English is not my native language so I am a little bit confused. Which message is grammatically correct?

> 1. Hold the screen to fly
> 2. Hold on to the screen to fly
> 3. Hold your finger on the screen to fly

If anybody has displayed a similar message in their game, can you share it with me?

Comment: press and hold? I am not a gamer, so I am probably not the person for this.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options:

> Press and hold your finger to the screen to fly

or

> Press (Hold) your finger to the screen to fly

or

> Hold your finger to the screen to fly

more verbose

> Touch your finger to the screen to begin flying, remove your finger to stop flying.

I'd focus more on making maybe a little tutorial that demonstrates the concept than sweating the wording.

Comment: How about "Hold your finger on the screen..." ? Is this also a correct usage? I am planning to use this sentence on tutorial. Unfortunately I can't create a visual tutorial.

Comment: I think that people would most likely understand, but "labeling and instruction" is a very different field than normal writing. This comes from my personal experience, but they pay people lots of money to come up with the correct wording for instruction manuals so people won't misunderstand and hurt themselves on products. In this case I prefer "press and hold" over "hold, because it tells you every step on the action rather than one part of it

Answer (score -1):

My programmer hubby says to be very clear use: Press, hold and swipe.